# Conditional Fomatting ranges that match another range

Tags: excel, range, conditional-formatting

I'm creating a project in excel, and I want my cells to be automatically colored.

In what way can I color the cells in the range of C3: G16 with respect
to the cells equal to column A?

```css
table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableizer-table">
   <thead>
         <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
              <th>A</th>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
              <th>5</th>
              <th>6</th>
              <th>7</th>
              <th>8</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td>19/8/19</td>
        <td>19/8/2019</td>
        <td>20/8/2019</td>
        <td>21/8/2019</td>
        <td>22/8/2019</td>
        <td>23/8/2019</td>
        <td>24/8/2019</td>
        <td>25/8/2019</td>
        <td>26/8/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>19/8/19</td>
        <td>19/8/2019</td>
        <td>20/8/2019</td>
        <td>21/8/2019</td>
        <td>22/8/2019</td>
        <td>23/8/2019</td>
        <td>24/8/2019</td>
        <td>25/8/2019</td>
        <td>26/8/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>19/8/19</td>
        <td>19/8/2019</td>
        <td>20/8/2019</td>
        <td>21/8/2019</td>
        <td>22/8/2019</td>
        <td>23/8/2019</td>
        <td>24/8/2019</td>
        <td>25/8/2019</td>
        <td>26/8/2019</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Desired outcome:

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see your excel file, these are HTML and CSS files. if you can use CSS3 you'll be able to apply style to cells using `first`, `next`, `prev`, `last` or even based on text in cell

Comment: @AaA It is not desirable to upload excel files, I for one wont open them any ways due to security concerns.

Comment: @Luuklag, what I meant was the screenshot that is there now.

Answer (score 1):

Select range C3 to G16. Create a new conditional format rule with a formula, enter the formula `=$A3=C3`, and set the format that you want.